# Task bar pops up during full screen games

Tags: windows-10

So when I play Minecraft on full screen on Windows 10, it works well, until I suddenly look down/up.

When that happens, my mouse hovers at the bottom/top of the screen(its not locked for some reason) and the taskbar/the bar at the top pops up and if i accidentally click on that, it opens up some other app..

This is really annoying, especially in pvp. Is there anyway I can fix that?

EDIT: BTW its minecraft windows 10 edition. This does not happen in java minecraft

Comment: How is Minecraft configured? Full screen? Windowed, Windowed fullscreen no borders? Try setting it to windowed and back to fullscreen.

Comment: its on full screen. I did try setting it to windowed and back to full screen but nothing happened. Have been having this problem for like an year now..

Comment: BTW its minecraft windows 10 edition. This does not happen in java minecraft